# Is it possible to update manifest file of .appxupload file in Windows store app?

Tags: xml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have one .appxupload package. I have no access to source code. I want to update some values in that, which is shown in below images. Is it possible to directly update from .appxupload package ?

I know it's an archive file only. `Package.appxmanifest` is converted to `AppxManifest.xml` and it warns **Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.** But I have no access to .appxmanifest file.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Getting error `Error: The package is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted.`

Comment: Maybe the better question -- what are you trying to achieve/why are you trying to make these changes to an app package? Why don't you have the source files?

Answer (score 0):

Actually an app downloaded from windows store is linked directly to a publisher name in Case you try changing it you will get an error. In case you are dveloping it will take Default machine Name .. I have some thing like CN=Anobikd . But incase uploaded to the store the app must always corrospond to a particular publisher. Here's a Blog you can go through it.

[Metro Style store app blog](http://peterdn.com/post/To-make-a-Metro-Appx-Package-from-scratch-you-must-first-e280a6.aspx)
Heres some lines from the blog.
**Publisher must be the name of the root certificate that you will generate later.  If these do not correspond, you will not be able to sign the app.  Choose something sensible for the moment, such as “CN=my.domain.com”.**

Thats one of the reason why you get a digitally corrupt signature or not digitally signed error.

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to modify ?

Comment: Read this for more info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx

 and also 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211474.aspx 
 
Actually the publisher of the app creates the signed certificate. And clearly mentioned that after you have signed the app then you cannot change the manifest file later.

Comment: [From](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211474.aspx), **After signing, you can't modify the manifest without invalidating the package signature.** Do you know how can I invalidate & re-sign the package with newer signature ?

Comment: yes theres a procedure mentioned When I was going through the links. Wait Ill share

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832(v=vs.85).aspx

  Heres the link .. Test it I guess it would create a new certificate for testing or deploying app locally :). Havent my self done so far till date but you can give a try and let me know.

Comment: And also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj835836.aspx  follow the steps here in case of any invalid entry or error

Comment: @Xyroid Did it help to create a new certificate ? I mean the app from the link ? i myself m curious to know :)